# In Maven multi-module project, how can i get one module's buildVersion from another module?

Tags: maven, build, properties

I am trying to collect the build version including timestamp `${unqualifiedVersion}.${buildQualifier}` information for all the modules in one module.
But after some test, the `${unqualifiedVersion}.${buildQualifier}` value can only be identified inside the child module.

Is there a way i can share this value across modules?

Comment: Isn't the build qualifier the same for all the modules?

Comment: no, the ${buildQualifier} is different in each module.

Comment: So what is this build qualifier? Why is it different? Usually, all modules are build with exactly the same version.

Comment: Here is a document illustrates the meaning of ${buildQualifier} and other variables.
https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-packaging-plugin/plugin-info.html

Comment: Can you generate the buildQualifier in the parent POM and then use it in all modules, so that it is the same everywhere?

Comment: It could be done in that way, but the buildQualifier has necessity to be differentiated for each child module, for example you can find out base on the timeStamp which ones are recently modified.

Comment: But in a build,  you build all modules. Why do they need slightly different timestamps?

Comment: It is for RCP app update site, there could be more than 1 version in target folder, the timestamp is to identify them.

Comment: Yes, no problem with that. Let me try to be more concrete. Say you have multi-module project with 5 modules. Either you determine the timestamp `t` first and build all the modules with it, so all five modules have timestamp `t` (from the beginning of the build). Or, what you do, you determine a timestamp in each of the five modules, so module1 has timestamp `t+1` and module2 has timestamp `t+2` and so on. I do not see an advantage in the second solution. The first also guarantees that the different builds have different timestamps.

Comment: Yes, I think you mentioned a very good point, and it is completely feasible. I am dealing with a legacy system and all the characters stated above is the "as-is" status,  the reason I was obsessed is because I don't want massive changes to the system. But if sharing different `${buildQualifier}` across modules turns out to be not possible, i will do it the way you mentioned.
Thank you~